# LR4: Cannot pan using arrow keys

Tags: lightroom-4

When viewing an image in zoomed mode, the up-down arrow keys do not allow me to pan in it. I have not found any other shortcuts to pan without using the mouse.

Comment: Thanks but not a duplicate

Answer (score 0):

You can use the PageUp and PageDown keys to pan.

- **PageUp** -> Pan up
- **PageDown** -> Pan down
- **Shift + PageUp** -> Pan left
- **Shift + PageDown** -> Pan right

Found this over at the [Adobe forums](https://forums.adobe.com/message/5112124#5112124)

Comment: That definitely does not work for me.